# Drupal: where does this tab "Track" come from?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've noticed there is one more tab in my edit-content pages in Drupal.

Could you tell me which plugin added it ?

See picture: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/TrackTab.png

I actually need to know step by step how can I disable such tab

thanks

Comment: you can edit your question - please do so, including your comment (and delete latter).

Comment: I've edited my question and delete previous comment. I don't think I'm that guy, I accept my answers and answers of other people as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

besides `tracker.module` (and, as mingos said, possibly other contrib modules), a "Track" tab is also added (to nodes) by `statistics.module`, [`statistics_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/statistics_menu/6).

**UPDATE**: this tab is only visible to users with "access statistics" permissions, so just adjust your site's permissions accordingly. as user #1 you will always see it, though.

you can, of course, just disable `statistics.module`.

Comment: mhm could you tell me how can I remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Either Tracker (core module) or Tracker 2 (add-on) adds such a tab, but I've noticed it only on user profile pages.

Comment: mhm could you tell me how can I remove it ?

Comment: it is already disabled, unchecked, in the site Building > Modules page. I've actually never used it, that's why I'm surprised to see this new tab. Probably some other module is using it ?

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible. You have to check the modules list and see what contrib modules you have enabled, then look for some info about them on drupal.org - I'm sure you'll eventually find the correct one. Or simply experiment with enabling/disabling random modules :).